# Finding first and last positive values in an Fortran array

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have an integer array.  Several of the values are zero, at least a few are greater than zero.  I would like to find the locations of the first and last positive values in the array.  This can be done with loops, of course.  But what with modern Fortran array capabilities, I am thinking there must be something more compact and elegant.  But nothing is coming to me.  Anyone know of a good way to do this?

Comment: I don't tkink there is anything like that, it is really too specialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Fortran 2008 feature `findloc` it is possible.

First, you need to convert your values such that all positive values have the same value, as `findloc` find a specified value. I have used `sign` for this, so that all positive values are equal to `1`.

`findloc(data, 1)` returns the first positive value (if you have only -1,+1 values of course) and `findloc(data, 1, back=.true.)` the last one. Example program below.

```
program find_positive
  implicit none

  integer, allocatable :: data(:)

  data = [-3,  3,  0,  2, -3]
  write(*,*) data
  data = sign(1, data)
  write(*,*) data

  write(*,*) findloc(data, 1)
  write(*,*) findloc(data, 1, back=.true.)

end program find_positive
```

I have tested this with Intel Fortran 2018. gfortran just included the feature but my version of gfortran (8.2.0) does not have it yet.

PS: no idea about the performance for your needs, but the feature is there :-)

EDIT: shorter version as suggested by High Performance Mark

```
program find_positive
  implicit none

  integer, allocatable :: data(:)

  data = [-3,  3,  0,  2, -3]
  write(*,*) data

  write(*,*) findloc(sign(1, data), 1)
  write(*,*) findloc(sign(1, data), 1, back=.true.)

end program find_positive
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible and in fact quite obvious, but computing `data = sign(1, data)` seems like WAY too much excessive work for me. The larger the array the worse will it be.

Comment: `findloc(sign(1,data),1)` should work too, no need to explicitly declare the auxiliary array.

Comment: @VladimirF many of these high-level operations have a cost and the tradeoff must be chosen depending on the context. I do not hide this.

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, my gfortran doesn't have it either, and I don't have access to Intel.  Will keep this in mind.  Thanks again.

Comment: [equation.com](http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=fortran) has windows' binaries for the lastest snapshots of gfortran, if you wanted try the new features.

Answer (score 5):

I am forced to answer because the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53488617/5713492) is baroque and incorrect. My answer is based on the fact that FINDLOC works with LOGICAL ARRAY= and VALUE= arguments:

```
program find
   integer, allocatable :: data(:)
   data = [-3, 3, 2, 0, -2]
   write(*,'(*(g0))') 'First Positive = ',findloc(data > 0, .TRUE.)
   write(*,'(*(g0))') 'Last Positive = ',findloc(data > 0, .TRUE., BACK = .TRUE.)
   write(*,*) findloc(sign(1, data), 1)
   write(*,*) findloc(sign(1, data), 1, back=.true.)
end program find
```

Output with gcc version 9.0.0 20181125 (experimental) (GCC) from equation.com:

```
First Positive = 2
Last Positive = 3
           2
           4
```

Note that the SIGN intrinsic gives false positives if argument B= is zero.

Comment: Nice solution :-) I am afraid that it does not work with ifort or gfortran 8.2 however... We'll need to wait a bit for updates. In what way is my answer incorrect?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Yeah, that equation.com build of gfortran doesn't actually work, just well enough to compile my example however. Look at the DATA array in my example: the correct value for the last positive value is #3 as my approach yields whereas your code produces a result of #4. Easy enough to fix for an INTEGER array as in the original statement of the problem, but isn't it a little trickier for a REAL array? Can you supply such a fix, that works in the presence or absence of -0.0?